# LibreOffice menu icons are missing

Tags: libreoffice

Instead of the menu icons there is only text "New", "Open", "Save" etc. on the buttons.
Before everything was ok and I don't know what happened. 
To fix the problem I installed the newest version of LibreOffice 14.3.5 but it didn't help.
My Ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS 64-bit.

[image]

Comment: are you able to get into the `view` menu entry? There would be an option `symbols > adjust` where this can be fixed

Comment: Yes there is View menu entry but I cannot find the option Symbols and Adjust. Where is it exactly?

Comment: is there a way I can send you a screenshot? (email?)

Comment: @LittleByBlue: just answer the question and post the screenshot there...  ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to set the language to English an I do not think that German would be usefull.